# Image Encryption

Tags: jakarta-ee

Input image is in .jpeg format.I am reading image pixel by pixel.Then performing X-OR operation for each pixels by a hard-coded Key value such as 101 and writing the damaged pixels to other file .while trying to get back original image ,image is not same it gets distorted.
How can I get the original image?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JPEG image format uses a lossy compression algorithm. This means that some information is lost when you save the "encrypted" image, and this likely causes distortions. To avoid distortions use an image format without compression or with lossless compression, such as PNG.

Comment: He should encrypt the compressed data, instead of compressing the encrypted data.

Comment: I have searched about image encryption and I found that .JPEG is lossy format but  doubt is whether in .JPEG format can distortion be minimized further to get similar image compared to original ?

Comment: I am not compressing the data ,I am X-orring the original pixels .